# How to know that if my account wallet is on mainnet or testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, goethe

Is there any way to detect account wallet is on mainnet or goerli testnet ?

Answer (score 1):

Your wallet is not tied to a specific network, consisting of private and public keys (your address). The same private key and public address can be used across multiple networks such as mainnet and testnets.

To determine if your wallet is being used on mainnet or testnet, you need to check which network your wallet provider, or client is connected to. For example, you can use `getNetwork()` method on ethers.js:

```
await wallet.provider.getNetwork()
```